# jQuery-UI Sortable and string replace issue

Tags: regex, jquery-ui, replace

Consider the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tbody").sortable({
        handle: 'td:first',
        opacity: 0.75,
        helper: function (e, ui) {
            ui.children().each(function () {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return ui;
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("reorder triggered");
            // Re-order items based on position in table
            $(".dragablePager").each(function (index) {

                $(this).find("input").each(function () {
                    alert(index);
                    alert("old name: " + this.name);
                    oldname = this.name;
                    newname = oldname.replace(/\d+/, index);
                    this.name = newname;
                    alert("new name: " + this.name);
                    alert(newname);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The part of the form I am dealing with looks something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="dragablePager">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pagers[0][CellEmail]" value="REDACTED">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pagers[0][Message]" value="test 1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dragablePager">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pagers[1][CellEmail]" value="REDACTED">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pagers[1][Message]" value="sdfdsfdf">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dragablePager">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pagers[2][CellEmail]" value="REDACTED">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pagers[2][Message]" value="3247678">
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

What I am tying to do is change the indexes of the input elements based on their order in the table, after the user is done dragging. The problem is that for some reason the very simple RegEx that I have tested using a RegEx tester refuses to work. oldname and newname are always the same.

I am going nuts; what the hell am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am getting this output in my console for the code posted in the first comment:

```
0
old name: pagers[1][CellEmail]
new name: pagers[1][CellEmail]
0
old name: pagers[1][Message]
new name: pagers[1][Message]
1
old name: pagers[2][CellEmail]
new name: pagers[2][CellEmail]
1
old name: pagers[2][Message]
new name: pagers[2][Message]
2
old name: pagers[0][CellEmail]
new name: pagers[0][CellEmail]
2
old name: pagers[0][Message]
new name: pagers[0][Message]
```

Here is the code from that comment (nearly identical to my original):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tbody").sortable({
    handle: 'td:first',
    opacity: 0.75,
    helper: function(e, ui) {
      ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
      });
      return ui;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("reorder triggered");
      // Re-order items based on position in table
      $(".dragablePager").each(function(index) {

        $(this).find("input").each(function() {
          console.log(index);
          console.log("old name: " + this.name);
          oldname = this.name;
          newname = oldname.replace(/\d+/, index);
          console.log("new name: " + newname);
          this.name = newname;
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How can this possibly happen? Clearly something is wrong to get output like this.

Comment: [Working fine](https://jsfiddle.net/c5zk24qa/)

Comment: This fiddle works, but I am telling you it is NOT working on my actual page. also, why the downvotes? I am having a legitimate problem, If it "just worked" I wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: What can we do if it doesn't work in your page..? You have to give us the code required to reproduce the issue. Which you haven't. Try posting a [mcve]

Comment: I posted because I didn't know if it was just me; how would I have known that? Someone made it clear it wasn't. I elaborated. Don't see how that is in any way unreasonable.

Comment: It is unreasonable because you posted working code and told us it doesn't work. What are we supposed to do with working code..? You should have made sure this code reproduces the problem before posting it. If it doesn't, think why it happens just for you, and provide relevant information. which is not there in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. It was kind of dumb. I am creating the JS in a string in Perl, and I neglected to escape the \ in the regex. It should have been:

```
oldname.replace(/\\d+/, index);
```

Simply because it was in a heredoc.